# Street View Static Image API *not* returning most recent image

Tags: google-street-view-static-api

I am attempting to retrieve an image via the Static Image API, and I'd like that image to be the most recent image Google has. **However, the image that is returned is not the most recent image.**

In the example (1st link below), I am being returned an image from July 2020. However, when I go to that location in Street View (2nd link below), I see that there are multiple images that were taken more recently, including one in August 2023.

How do I return the most recent image via the API?

Example API request: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=640x640&location=35.6074054,-78.1272452&heading=29.663428957040054&fov=70&pitch=0&key=xyz

Example more recent Street View images: https://www.google.com/maps/@35.6073518,-78.1272711,3a,75y,32.45h,87.9t/data=!3m7!1e1!3m5!1snCEdgDSwb_xSIVSeoOk0gg!2e0!5s20230801T000000!7i16384!8i8192?entry=ttu